# How do I turn on the Emmet code abbreviation suggestions?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, settings, emmet

I thought I would be able to enable it these abbreviation suggestions, but I am not able to find any options to do.

These are the suggestions I am talking about:

[image: abbreviation]

I accidentally disabled the circled box. How do I enable them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things you should look at/try.

1. Perhaps you accidentally closed these abbreviation suggestions.  If that is the case, you can simply reopen them by clicking an arrow in the list of suggestions (see .gif):

[image: suggestion arrow]

2. Check your settings for Emmet, in particular, the `emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions` and `emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation`.  In the screenshot below, these are the default settings:

[image: emmet settings]